# how to get percentage in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have  stored procedure in which i am getting category presence by its count.I want its total percentage. samples are my total values . I need percentage of yes or no out of samples. please help. My stored procedure is given below.

```
BEGIN

SELECT 

    SC.name as SC,
    SUM(IF(is_category_present = 1, 1, 0)) as YES,
    SUM(IF(is_category_present = 0, 1, 0)) as NO,
    COUNT(OC.outlet_id) as SAMPLE

FROM outlet_categories OC
INNER JOIN outlets O on O.id = OC.outlet_id
INNER JOIN sale_channels SC on SC.id = O.sale_channel_id

WHERE OC.month = month
AND CASE WHEN location_type = 1 THEN OC.zone_id = location
         WHEN location_type = 2 THEN OC.state_id = location
         WHEN location_type = 3 THEN OC.city_id = location

    END
AND OC.category_id = category_id

GROUP BY SC.id;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple calculation should work:

```
(SUM(IF(is_category_present = 1, 1, 0))*1.0) / COUNT(OC.outlet_id) * 100.0 AS perc_yes
(SUM(IF(is_category_present = 0, 1, 0))*1.0) / COUNT(OC.outlet_id) * 100.0 AS perc_no
```

Comment: Cast it to `varchar`, use `CONCAT` and add `%` sign.

Comment: and what about samples, samples should show 100% . means total of yes or no? can you add that in your query too

Comment: I want its rounded value with percentage.. please edit your answer for more clearance

Comment: How about trying something on your own and actually looking at the documentation or at least try searching? I've given you the keywords to do that.